# Oracel SQL - How can I show the data in the columns

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to list for each counterparty their name, vendor no. and customer no. Similar to the table below

[image]

I wrote this SQL, which will have two rows for each counterparty and in the column value, it will have the Vendor no, and the Customer no. I want to have instead one row per counterparty and have the Vendor no, and the Customer no as separate columns.

```
SELECT par.short_name
        ,inf.value
    FROM party_info inf
        ,party_info_types typ
        ,party par
    WHERE inf.type_id = typ.type_id
        AND inf.party_id = par.party_id
        AND typ.type_id IN (
            21185
            ,21186
            ) -- Vendor no / Customer no
```

This is the current output from the sequel

[image]

Comment: Is that sample table data or the expected result? We need both anyway.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Do not repost the same question twice.

Comment: As I commented on your previous post, this just requires a `PIVOT` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EwSdU8ju).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, 21185 and 21186 are entangled. For these particular rows you can achieve your goal like this:

```
select t21185.name as name21185,
       t21185.value as value21185,
       t21186.name as name21186,
       t21186.value as value21186
from (
SELECT par.name
        ,inf.value
    FROM party_info inf
        ,party_info_types typ
        ,party par
    WHERE inf.type_id = typ.type_id
        AND inf.party_id = par.party_id
        AND typ.type_id = 21185
) t21185, (
SELECT par.name
        ,inf.value
    FROM party_info inf
        ,party_info_types typ
        ,party par
    WHERE inf.type_id = typ.type_id
        AND inf.party_id = par.party_id
        AND typ.type_id = 21186
) t21186
```

I have kept your query without a `join` for now, because I do not know enough about your schema to be comfortable doing large refactors. So, my understanding is that the entanglement of 21185 and 21186 is just an example and you have many such counterparts. If so, then you will need to somehow determine what makes two records counterparts of each-other.

I noticed though that in your example, an odd `typ.type_id` is on the left-hand-side, whereas a `typ.type_id` of a pair value being greater than the left-hand-side by exactly 1 is the right-hand-side. If that's a general pattern that you can safely use, then you can specify a criteria of

```
(t1.typ_id MOD 2 = 1) and (t2.typ_id = t1.typ_id + 1)
```

of course, you need some refactor to apply such a criteria, which I did not do for you in my answer, as I'm not yet sure that the pattern I have outlined in the criteria above applies to your problem-space.

Comment: Thanks, I just ran your SQL in the database, but it didn't return anything:-( I also attached the output from my original query. You can see for example for Agis, both type_id 20085
and 20086 will show data in the column Value. There are thousands of counterparties, but only 2 type_id. So for each counterparty, I want to show the data for type_id 20085
and 20086

Comment: @Skywalker can you edit your question and show what exactly did you try? Also, can you tell me whether the first subquery in the query in my answer yields values?